# MultipleBagFetchException with OneToOne relation

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

the following Hibernate entity structure consists of classes B and C, which inherit from abstract class A. D shall hold OneToOne relations to B and C.

Unfortunately, this results in an org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException when deploying EAR. I use JBoss EAP 6.1 with Hibernate 4.2.7.SP1.

Class A:

```
package my.sandbox;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class A {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Class B:

```
package my.sandbox;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_B")
public class B extends A {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "b")
    private D d;

    public D getD() {
        return d;
    }

    public void setD(D d) {
        this.d = d;
    }
}
```

Class C:

```
package my.sandbox;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_C")
public class C extends A {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "c")
    private D d;

    public D getD() {
        return d;
    }

    public void setD(D d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

}
```

Class D:

```
package my.sandbox;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_D")
public class D {

    @OneToOne
    private B b;

    @OneToOne
    private C c;

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public C getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be the inheritance of B and C from A. When B and C don't inherit from A, everything is fine. But since B and C have many similar attributes and a common hibernate sequence, I'd like to use this super class.

I've tried to add a FetchType to @OneToOne in D (both EAGER and LAZY) and to remove mappedBy in B and C. It didn't help.

Because of the inheritance from A, I couldn't set any foreign key constraints from D to B and C in the underlying database.

Any hints on my problem? Thank you in advance.

Kind regards
Stefan